# Populate a table view with user info with Google Sign In

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to populate a tableview with the user info from a Google Sign In.

Here is the part of the table view I'm trying to populate. Basically, the First Name, Last Name and Email:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  long section = [indexPath section];
  long row = [indexPath row];

  if (section == 0) {
  // Section: Details
  if (tableView.editing) {
  if (row == 0) {
    // Row: First Name
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FirstNameCell"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = manager.currentAccount.firstName;
    return cell;
  } else if (row == 1) {
    // Row: Last Name
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LastNameCell"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = manager.currentAccount.lastName;
    return cell;
  } else if (row == 2) {
    // Row: Email
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmailCell"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = manager.currentAccount.email;
    return cell;

    ...
```

I believe the method where I'm retrieving the user info is here:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
     // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
     NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
     NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
     NSString *name = user.profile.name;
     NSString *email = user.profile.email;
     // ...
```

I just don't know how to populate the table view. Or should this be done automatically by Google Sign In?

Comment: are you able to get the sign in data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am or not. I just think the documentation lacks a bit.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `didSignInForUser` delegate method. Then you can inspect the user object and see if you got the sign-in data.

Comment: Ok William, I'll try that. I'm pretty sure I'm signing in though, just that the user info isn't being passed to the table views i.e first name, last name and email

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saving user data after login in manager.currentAccount

You need to refresh you table view after sing in process in delegate method, because signing is is done in asynch mode. So your

```
 - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error
```

should look like:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Populating data to manager.currentAccount from (GIDGoogleUser *)user
        // ....
        // ....

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }   
}
```

Comment: When I add the `[self.tableView reloadData];` into that method, I get an error. ERROR: Property 'tableView' not found on 'LoginViewController' object. I also tried adding it to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but it says 'Code will never be executed'

Answer (score 0):

when you received google data store that data in one array.
after that just reload table in the method where you store data in an array

your table structore should be like this

```
#pragma matk table delegates
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return array.count;
}
```

try to create custom cell to show information you fetched from google login

below is sample custom cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTournamentsTableCell *cell = (MyTournamentsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[MyTournamentsTableCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTournamentsTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

      }
 return  cell;

}
```

you can read more here about how show data on table cell

[show data on table](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

[table view tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to the answers it seems that you have a `TableView` inside a `UIViewController`.

To fix this you can try to:

- Create an IBOutlet for that `TableView` in your `UIViewController` called `tableView`
- Set the `TableView`'s `dataSource` and `delegate` to that `UIViewController`
- Since you want to get only the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `email` **return 3** from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method.
- Place `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside `signIn:didSignInForUser:` method

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still getting an error when I do a `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside `signIn:didSignInForUser:`. I created and IBOutlet, but not sure if I did "Set the TableView's dataSource and delegate to that UIViewController"